# What's wrong with my basic style properties through json_encode array?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, json, dom

I have a Javascript Calendar in an `<table id="calendario">`, which allows me to manipulate the table through `calendario.rows[i].cells[i]`.

This Calendar allows the user to make a Reservation and gives the option of closing the day when the user feels it has already too many reservations.

I save his option in a boolean variable and the correspondent position, `calendario.rows[i].cells[i]`, in a string to a **SQL DB**.

When I save a single result from the query in a javascript variable I can successfully change the style property color, but when I loop through a resulting array nothing changes in my page.

I have 2 columns in the `"reservation"` table called `"Closed"` *(which holds the boolean 0 or 1)* and `"Position"` *(which holds the string calendario.rows[i].cells[i])*

**when I fetch one result of the array:**

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $position = $row["Position"];
    }
```

**then I save it in a Javascript variable:**

```
<script>
var red_day =  <?php echo $position; ?>;
</script>
```

**Then I use a function to change the style and print my result for testing purposes:**

```
<script> 
color_red(red_day);
function color_red(position){
position.style.color = "red";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = position;
}
</script>
```

I get the last day painted in red and in the "result" `<div>` I get **`[object HTMLTableCellElement]`**.

**When I try:**

```
$phparray = array();
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$phparray[] = $row["Position"];
}
```

**Then save it in Javascript and call a function:**

```
<script>
var jsarray = <?php echo json_encode($phparray); ?>;
result(jsarray){
var  text, pLen, i;
pLen = jsarray.length;
text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < pLen; i++) {
jsarray[i].style.color = "red";
 text += "<li>" + jsarray[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";


document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;
}
```

**Now I don't have any cell painted in red but I get the following result in var text:**

> calendario.rows[4].cells[1]
>
> calendario.rows[5].cells[5]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are calling color_red() before its definition